# Grails wrong response encoding for scaffold pages

Tags: grails, scaffolding, grails-2.3

After grails upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.3.6 I got wrong encoding for scaffold pages
For usual pages all is ok:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Same layout template used, but for scaffold page:

```
 Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "html" // none, html, base64
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"

grails {
  views {
    gsp {
      encoding = 'UTF-8'
      htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
      codecs {
        expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
        scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
        taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
        staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
      }
    }
  }
}
```

layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In new test application all work correctly.

Where I can find response encoding settings?

Comment: do you have added the lastest scaffolding plugin e.g. ``compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"`` in ``BuildConfig.groovy``?  had you ran ``install-templates`` in your installation beforehand and therefor have wrong templates flying around?

Comment: Yes, compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2" had been added. Hm. I have template of web.xml. I check it now

Comment: Old web.xml does not affect the encoding

Comment: I in debugger, I sow, that this request is processed by Rest plugin. As result, we have wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been fixed by replacing old configuration in Config.groovy (from grails 1.3, 2.3)

```
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                      xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
                      text: 'text/plain',
                      js: 'text/javascript',
                      rss: 'application/rss+xml',
                      atom: 'application/atom+xml',
                      css: 'text/css',
                      csv: 'text/csv',
                      all: '*/*',
                      json: ['application/json','text/json'],
                      form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
                    ]
```

By defoult config from grails 2.3

```
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
                      all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
                      atom:          'application/atom+xml',
                      css:           'text/css',
                      csv:           'text/csv',
                      form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                      js:            'text/javascript',
                      json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
                      multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
                      rss:           'application/rss+xml',
                      text:          'text/plain',
                      hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
                      xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
```